# Regular expression to check there is only first name

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if user typed first name and last name in form field, and that's easy. Problem is that I want to let user type only first name and my expression doesn't allow for that. How should I rebuild my expression to do that?

```js
var nameReg = new RegExp("^[A-Z-zóąśłżźćńÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ ][a-z-zóąśłżźćńÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ ]{2,20} [A-Z-zóąśłżźćńÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ][a-z-zóąśłżźćńÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ]{1,35}$");

if(!nameReg.test(cname)) {  
    alert('Letters only in name field');
    return false;   
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this, /^[a-zA-Z]+$/

Comment: Because your expression allows spaces in different places, how could you distinguish between a first and last name? Far better and easier would be to use two form fields.

Comment: That expression will work only for first name, user could not type last name and don't allow polish signs,

I know that two fields will be much easier, but i prefer to do that with one field. My expression allow spaces only after first typed word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty straight forward

```
  ^[A-Za-zóąśłżźćńÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ]{2,20}[\s]*$
```

- this will match only a string starts with any letters (and those signs)
- and ends with any of those letters or any number of white spaces
- But won't match if it encounters any none space characters after that

For explanation see this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JwyOHM/1) snippet

Comment: ^[A-Za-zóąśłżźćńÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ ]{2,20}[\s]*$

With added space works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i
```

because first name can contain name like this

```
Ashley D'souza
Martin Luther King, Jr.
Hector Sausage-Hausen
```

Comment: In my country it almost impossible to contain that signs in names ;) But thanks for advise :)